# executing queries with and without indexes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-indexes

I have to run the same queries with and without indexes, in mysql. 
I create indexes like this:

```
create index index_1 on table_1(column_name);
create index index_2 on table_2(column_name);
```

I execute this and I get the results that 0 rows has affected, both times. Is this ok?

Because when I execute the queries I have (after I created indexes), it takes me the same time as before (without indexes.)

The view of database: 
[image: click here for the image]

I have multiple small queries about this database, e.g

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.customer_id, customers.customer_name
FROM customers
  INNER JOIN accounts ON customers.customer_id = accounts.customer_id
  INNER JOIN transactions ON transactions.account_id = accounts.account_id 
WHERE transactions.trn_date >= '2011/05/01'
  AND transactions.trn_date <= '2011/05/31'
ORDER BY customers.customer_id
```

Comment: Too little info. We need table definitions, queries etc.

Comment: And the indexes are?

Comment: We have to create, at our discretion, 2 indexes,  on the base tables to reduce the execution time of the queries and still have the slight increase in loading time of new data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need these indexes for that query:

```
transactions: INDEX(trn_date)
accounts:     INDEX(account_id)
customers:    INDEX(customer_id)
```

In the last two cases, you probably already have that column as the `PRIMARY KEY`.  If so, do not add a redundant `INDEX`.

Answer (score 1):

> I execute this and I get the results that 0 rows has affected, both
>   times. Is this ok?

Yes, it is ok.
There are DDL operation which create new object and shouldn't output something.

> Because when I execute the queries I have (after I created indexes) it
>   takes me the same time as before (without indexes)

The queries haven't to use index. The internal optimizer make decision in depend of data distribution. For example, if column_name.table_1 has 50 unique values, then index is not be used.

More details ou can found in official documentation: [9.3.1 How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysql-indexes.html)

Comment: We have to create, at our discretion, 2 indexes, on the base tables to reduce the execution time of the queries and still have the slight increase in loading time of new data @Pavel Zimogorov

Comment: You should calculate, the benefits of indexes for improving select queries and insert degradation. If you have intensive data load, I would recommend to create separate table for retrieving data (TRN_SELECT). And use TRN only for insert data and select rows for populating  TRN_SELECT